# Fedora preupgrade-cli fails

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I have an ancient version of Fedora which I'd like to upgrade. I have command line access only (through PuTTy on a Windows machine). From what I've read, `preupgrade-cli` is what I should be doing, but that always fails with the message "[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try."

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 9 (Sulphur)
[root@localhost ~]# preupgrade-cli
Loaded plugins: blacklist, refresh-packagekit, whiteout
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
please give a release to try to pre-upgrade to
valid entries include:
   "Fedora 16 (Verne)"
   "Fedora 15 (Lovelock)"
   "Fedora 13 (Goddard)"
   "Fedora 11 (Leonidas)"
   "Fedora 12 (Constantine)"
   "Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle)"
   "Fedora 14 (Laughlin)"
   "Fedora 10 (Cambridge)"
[root@localhost ~]# preupgrade-cli "Fedora 16 (Verne)"
Loaded plugins: blacklist, refresh-packagekit, whiteout
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
preupgrade-main (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-16&arch=$basearch
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-16&arch=i386
preupgrade (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?path=pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/$basearch/os/
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?path=pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/i386/os/
preupgrade-updates-newkey (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f16.newkey&arch=i386
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f16.newkey&arch=i386
Can't set up new repo preupgrade-updates-newkey - removing
preupgrade-fedora (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-16&arch=i386
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-16&arch=i386
preupgrade-updates (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f16&arch=i386
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f16&arch=i386
Fetched treeinfo from http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/i386/os//.treeinfo
treeinfo timestamp: Thu Nov  3 03:11:15 2011
.treeinfo                                                                                                                                                                               |  906 B     00:00
/boot/upgrade/vmlinuz checksum OK
/boot/upgrade/initrd.img checksum OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/preupgrade/preupgrade-cli.py", line 305, in <module>
    pu.main(myrelease)
  File "/usr/share/preupgrade/preupgrade-cli.py", line 204, in main
    stage2file = self.retrieve_non_critical_files()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/preupgrade/__init__.py", line 556, in retrieve_non_critical_files
    self._retrieve_file(self.mainimage,targetdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/preupgrade/__init__.py", line 437, in _retrieve_file
    tmp = self.instgrab.urlopen(fileinfo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/urlgrabber/mirror.py", line 417, in urlopen
    return self._mirror_try(func, url, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/urlgrabber/mirror.py", line 390, in _mirror_try
    mirrorchoice = self._get_mirror(gr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/urlgrabber/mirror.py", line 287, in _get_mirror
    raise URLGrabError(256, _('No more mirrors to try.'))
urlgrabber.grabber.URLGrabError: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
[root@localhost ~]# traceroute ftp.heanet.ie
traceroute to ftp.heanet.ie (193.1.193.64), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  0.318 ms  0.383 ms  0.584 ms
 2  b-ras1.pgs.portlaoise.eircom.net (159.134.155.8)  31.286 ms  34.831 ms  35.415 ms
 3  tenge-5-1-1.pe1.pgs.lmk-pgs.eircom.net (86.43.247.133)  39.728 ms  39.806 ms  40.421 ms
 4  tenge-7-1-1.core1.bdt.core.eircom.net (86.43.252.249)  48.627 ms  48.872 ms  48.938 ms
 5  * * *
 6  83.71.115.181 (83.71.115.181)  55.914 ms  33.992 ms  38.373 ms
 7  te0-0-0-1-cr2-cwt.hea.net (193.242.111.16)  83.851 ms  44.684 ms  44.839 ms
 8  te5-1-blanch-sr1.services.hea.net (193.1.236.2)  39.659 ms  40.871 ms  44.635 ms
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  te5-1-blanch-sr1.services.hea.net (193.1.236.2)  53.721 ms !X * *
```

Updating for Fedora 17 also fails. (I tried 16 first, because 17 is out of order in the list, so I never noticed it.)

```
[root@localhost ~]# preupgrade-cli "Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle)"
Loaded plugins: blacklist, refresh-packagekit, whiteout
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit
preupgrade-main (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-17&arch=$basearch
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-17&arch=i386
preupgrade (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?path=pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/$basearch/os/
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?path=pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Fedora/i386/os/
preupgrade-updates-newkey (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f17.newkey&arch=i386
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f17.newkey&arch=i386
Can't set up new repo preupgrade-updates-newkey - removing
preupgrade-fedora (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-17&arch=i386
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-17&arch=i386
preupgrade-updates (mirrorlist)
  url: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f17&arch=i386
  now: http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=updates-released-f17&arch=i386
Fetched treeinfo from http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/i386/os//.treeinfo
treeinfo timestamp: Thu Nov  3 03:11:15 2011
.treeinfo                                                                                                                                                                               |  906 B     00:00
/boot/upgrade/vmlinuz checksum OK
/boot/upgrade/initrd.img checksum OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/preupgrade/preupgrade-cli.py", line 305, in <module>
    pu.main(myrelease)
  File "/usr/share/preupgrade/preupgrade-cli.py", line 204, in main
    stage2file = self.retrieve_non_critical_files()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/preupgrade/__init__.py", line 556, in retrieve_non_critical_files
    self._retrieve_file(self.mainimage,targetdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/preupgrade/__init__.py", line 437, in _retrieve_file
    tmp = self.instgrab.urlopen(fileinfo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/urlgrabber/mirror.py", line 417, in urlopen
    return self._mirror_try(func, url, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/urlgrabber/mirror.py", line 390, in _mirror_try
    mirrorchoice = self._get_mirror(gr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/urlgrabber/mirror.py", line 287, in _get_mirror
    raise URLGrabError(256, _('No more mirrors to try.'))
urlgrabber.grabber.URLGrabError: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Is there any way to get around this and install an upgrade, or would I be better off to back up my data, wipe, and start from scratch?

http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/17/ and http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/fedora-secondary/updates/17/ and http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/fedora-secondary/releases/17/Fedora/ all suggest that ftp.heanet.ie does host Fedora 17, but for some reason the preupgrade command is not finding it there. Should I use a different mirror (if so, how?) or reconfigure something else in the connection to ftp.heanet.ie?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from Fedora 9 to any currently-supported release of Fedora is probably impossible, there's just been too many changes and you'd have too much broken to make it worth it.  You'd end up spending more time fixing broken packages that no one has ever encountered because this isn't a supported upgrade path.  Back up and reinstall from fresh installation media.

Answer (score 0):

I would try upgrading to Fedora 17 - 15 might be old enough that mirrors have removed it, which seems to be the error you're getting. If that doesn't work, you're probably better off wiping and starting anew, since you'll probably spend more time getting the upgrade to work than you would simply restoring your data.

Comment: It looks like 17 isn't an option with the normal `preupgrade-cli`. Is there any way around that? Alternatively, would I have any luck finding a mirror which *did* have an earlier version of Fedora, and somehow forcing `preupgrade-cli` to use that mirror?

Comment: Your output says it is valid:  "Fedora 17 (Beefy Miracle)" is listed as a valid target. That's why I said 17 and not 18.

Comment: Oh flip. It's out of order, so I never noticed it. *doh*

Comment: That failed too (see updated question). But thanks for pointing it out to me. It's out of order in the list, so I never even noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded this netbook from Fedora 16 to 17 and then to 18, but *before* 16 went end-of-life. It can't be done in one step, check the upgrade notes for Fedora 17 and follow them; once Fedora 17 is A-OK (remember to run the cleanup commands suggested!) then go for Fedora 18.

Comment: Still, at the moment I'm stuck on Fedora 9. I did try upgrading one step at a time, but the upgrade to 10 failed too.

Comment: The do a fresh install. That is _way_ too old to update sanely (and the "clean update" did not work well in that timeframe yet).